# How can i use a button with php?

Tags: php

How can I use a button or form with PHP?

```
<button formmethod="GET" neme="1" type="button">click</button>
<?php 
    if ($_GET["1"]) {
        require_once "0000.php";
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM op");
        while ($rwo = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
            $rwo-> id;
        }
    }
?>
```

An error is always shown. What I am trying to do is if someone clicks on the button, results will show up.

Comment: And the error shown is... ?

Comment: This question is wrong in too many ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- typo `neme="1"` should be `name="1"`
- I think you still need a `<form>` tag wrapped around your button
- you'll probably want to `echo $rwo->id;` to see the results
- use `isset` to avoid undefined index notices
- use the input `type="submit"` instead of `type="button"`

---

```
<form>
    <button formmethod="GET" name="1" type="submit">click</button>
</form>
<?php 
    if (isset($_GET["1"])) {
        require_once "0000.php";
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM op");
        while ($rwo = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
            echo $rwo->id;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: That will only work if JS is involved and I doubt they are using JS, or didn't let us know about that. Two things: 1) Using `formmethod="GET"` without a value, will produce `?1=` so that should be omitted. 2) It will only work if the button type is a "submit" type and not a "button" type.

Comment: @Fred-ii- good catch with the button type - I have fixed it. But the formmethod works since we're checking if `isset($_GET["1"])`, so I don't follow your meaning on omission. Could you explain for me?

Comment: unless you're referring to the default form method is GET, so it's not necessary unless overriding an explicit `<form method="POST">`

Comment: Try it out and see Jeff, you'll see the url once you just change the button type and keep the rest ;-)